# Silk Performer Assignment of Load to agents has failed because at least one of the load agents is locked , unavailable, or has insufficient privileges

Tags: microfocus, silk-performer

I had been running my Silk tests on 8 agents. During my last run, i closed the test in between and since then, whenever i trigger the test, i see that it is not executing on few of the agents. Also, when i created a new workload and assigned them few agents(which were not running), I am getting the error "Assignment of Load to agents has failed because at least one of the load agents is locked , unavailable,  or has insufficient privileges".

I am not sure what is causing this issue since the Silk Agent Service is running. Also the agents are displaying as connected and even the Try Agent run goes fine. Request you to please suggest.

Silk Version - 18.5

Answer (score 0):

Agents may remain locked if there was a problem during last run and there are remaining temp files in C:\Users\Public\Documents\Silk Performer 18.5\LocalResults_

Save the results if they are meaningful for you and delete the folder to get the agent unlocked.